# Extract specific files in a tar archive using a wildcard

Tags: linux, unix, tar

I'm trying to create a script to extract only jpeg pictures from an archive containing many kind of files.

To do so, I tried to use:

```
   tar -xf MyTar.tar *.jpg
```

but it failed (*.jpg not found) and suggest me to use "--wildcard".
So I tried

```
tar -xf MyTar.tar --wildcard *.jpg
```

I did that, but then the same error and a different warning saying to me that the option "--wildcard" is ambiguous.

I've been over the man pages for tar, but didn't find a clue about the problem.

Comment: Which tar and which version? Paste the results of `tar --version`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In the end, I found then answer after a good break. The option is wildcard**s**, plural...

So the command

```
tar -xf MyTar.tar --wildcards "*.jpg"
```

did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

Put quotes around the wildcard like this `"*.jpg"` so the shell won't try expanding it and will instead pass it straight through to tar.  You want tar to evaluate the wildcard, not the shell and the quotes do that.

Answer (score 1):

For some older versions of tar,
the following is extracted from [the "man" file](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0210/6m6nb7mmp/index.html):

> Filename substitution  wildcards  cannot  be  used  for extracting files from the archive. Rather, use a command of the form:
>
> ```
> tar xvf ... /dev/rmt/0 `tar tf ... /dev/rmt/0 | grep 'pattern' `
> ```